# Saved sklearn model predicts differently than a trained one

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I trained simple RandomForestRegressor in sklearn:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

ran_for = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 300, min_samples_split = 2, 
   random_state = RND, n_jobs = 20, max_depth = 8, verbose = 2)
ran_for.fit(X_c, y_c)
```

Then I saved model via joblib:

```
from joblib import dump

dump(ran_for, '/content/random_forest_regressor.joblib')
```

After that I restarted my kernel, and loaded model, saved previously:

```
from joblib import load

my_model = load('/content/random_forest_regressor.joblib')
```

I tested saved model on the sample from same dataset:

```
pred = my_model.predict(X_test)
```

And it looks like my saved model is working completely wrong, here is the predictions unique values and baplot:

```
print(pd.Series(pred).unique())
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
pd.Series(pred).hist()
plt.show()
```

`[892.52446705 599.29566532 539.45592338 903.74387156 601.12144516]`

[predictions barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vOzj.png)

Am I doing smth wrong?

I am running this in Google Colab

**Edit:** As was suggested in comments, here is model prediction before saving:

```
pred = ran_for.predict(X_test)
print(pred[:20])
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
pd.Series(pred).hist(bins = 1000).set_xlim([0, 5000])
plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IXdG.png)
Here you can see, that model is predicting values properly.

Comment: You'd need to show us the predictions before saving-and-reloading, to demonstrate that this is actually different.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's Google Colab issues. Tried same on my local machine - works fine.